# Private replies for comments

Tags: comments

Currently in the Comments section, if you (the admin) wants to reply to a pending comment, perhaps to warn them or whatever, the only way to send the reply is by clicking 'Approve and Reply'.

Is there a way to send a private message to the submitted email address (besides manually writing an email) before approving the comment?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way in the WordPress Core to send private messages. That's what the email address is for. But why would you want an extra contact form for that?

Comment: Well for example, if a user is using profane language in a pending comment. You don't want to approve it. You don't want to email that user either because you don't want to give them your personal email. If you could relay the message from WordPress it would be much less confrontational and more authoritative.